# How to have a Vimeo video pick up from where it left off when the page is reloaded with cookie?

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, vimeo, vimeo-player

I already know that you can have an embedded Vimeo video start from a certain point by adding this line of code #t=0m0s to the iframe source, but what I'm trying to achieve is to have the time the viewer is on the page be cookied so it can set the start point when they return.

This way the video picks up where they left off.

I know the values can be passed with cookies so I'm assuming it's possible, I just don't have the javascript knowledge to wrap my head around it.

Any ideas if this is actually possible?

Comment: you can't reliably detect when someone leaves a page. but for the times when it does actually work, simply use the onunload or whatever mechanism to capture the video's current position, stuff it into a cookie, and put it back into the player if/when the user returns.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do exactly this. Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @user2101461 I know it's been a very long time, but I am in the same spot now. Do you have any code related to this which I can explore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use our [JavaScript API](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) to listen for the `playProgress` event to record how far along they are in the video, then use the `beforeunload` event on `window` to store the value that you have in a cookie.